# JavaFX 8 multiple css files for each component?

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am currently learning how to style my JavaFX 8 application via CSS.
The possibilities are a bit overwhelming at the moment though :/.

My situation:
I have a library for my project, which contains some UI parts, like dialogs or custom buttons and so on.
I want these parts to have an individual standard style.

My try is to give each component his own stylesheet which is then also located in the library.

But does this even work and how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. Just add the relevant stylesheet(s) to each of the components that needs them. Assuming they are instances of `Parent`, just call `getStylesheets().add(...)`.

Comment: Ok, what des "instances of parent" exactly mean? And when i do this in the construcot of the component for example. Wouldnt the css be loaded twice when i have two instances of the component?

Comment: I just mean that the custom controls to which you want to add the stylesheet are instances of the class [`Parent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html) (which defines the [`getStylesheets()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getStylesheets--))  -i.e. that the custom class defining the control is a subclass of `Parent`. The constructor would be a perfectly good place to do that. You state in the question that you want each component to have its own stylesheet, so I'm not sure what the last part of the comment means.

Comment: I dont really know how the stylecheats are handled internally, when i put 3 of the same component (3 instances) in my application, will there be problems because the stylecheet will get loaded 3 times (once for each) ?

Comment: Why do you need to? It's not really clear what you're asking. Have you actually tried adding the stylesheets to the controls you are creating? does it work? If not, what's actually going wrong?

Comment: What kind of problems are you referring to?